# ADO.Net: Sharing entities (.edmx) between multiple projects within a solution

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio, asp.net-mvc-2, ado.net

I've got three C# ASP.NET MVC2 projects within a single solution.  Names have been changed for simplicity's sake.

The solution is MY_COMPANY_SITES.

It's got three projects in it: CUSTOMER_SITE, INTRANET_SITE, CENTRAL_REPOSITORY.

...Both the CUSTOMER_SITE and INTRANET_SITE projects have their own ADO.Net entity models, generated via EDMX, and connect to their own databases.  The CENTRAL_REPOSITORY project contains a third ADO.Net entity model, linked up with its own database.

It is required for my situation that these three databases be separate; would take too long to explain here.

What I need to do: Give both the CUSTOMER_SITE and INTRANET_SITE access to the CENTRAL_REPOSITORY ADO.Net entities, in addition to their own.

i.e., the following code should work:

```
CUSTOMER_Entities custDb = new CUSTOMER_Entities();
CENTRAL_Entities ctrDb = new CENTRAL_Entities();

StoreLocation firstLoc = ctrDB.StoreLocations.First();

List<Order> orders = (from n in custDb.Orders
                        where n.LocationID == firstLoc.LocationID
                        select n).ToList();
```

...I'd also ideally prefer that if I modify the entity model within the CENTRAL_REPOSITORY, it's just linked to by the other applications so I don't have to copy all my changes among all three.

I figure there must be a "right" way to do this.  Could very much use some help understanding how.

Thanks!

**UPDATE:**

Blindy (below) directed me to find that the answer is just to right-click on the "References" within the CUSTOMER_SITE in the Solution Explorer, and click "Add Reference...", then select the CENTRAL_REPOSITORY project, and click OK.  And voila, everything shoud just work.

However, it doesn't actually seem to just work.  Specifically, I'm getting this error when I try to access the CENTRAL_REPOSITORY's data entities from within the CUSTOMER_SITE or INTRANET_SITE:

```
The specified named connection is either not found in the configuration, not intended to be used with the EntityClient provider, or not valid.
```

...so there's some problem with trying to use the entities from that project, and I'm not understanding what.  Any thoughts?

Comment: If you already have the third project referenced by the other two, you can do this exactly as you wrote. What's the problem here exactly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To answer your question, you need to have the appropriate connection string in your configuration of the other two sites, to enable your CENTRAL_REPOSITORY to use it to connect.  Have a look in the original site config and copy that connection to the other two sites.

Answer (score 0):

You need to create a connection string in the app.config file for each project that uses the linq to entities model to solve this error.